# ElasticSearch bulk update

Tags: elasticsearch

Say we have an documents to index all students information (fields city & name) .

At a point If I want to update city of all students with prefix  like  "NY -" all in one strech.  Can this be done?

eg:
David Auburn 
Jack Jamestown
Claire Newburgh

Now I need an Single API or ES call which changes all the above documents to

eg:
David NY-Auburn 
Jack NY-Jamestown
Claire NY-Newburgh

I know there is way we can do it one update for each document. but i need ALL DOCUMENTS IN ONE GO

Thanks
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update by query does not exist in ES. I don'think the underlying lucene indices have a way to update, they delete and re-add always.

[There is some talk about it becoming a thing, maybe in 1.0?](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1607)

There is a [plugin that can do update by query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/)

You could write a quick script to read and re-post all your docs using any of the [ES clients](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/unleash-the-clients-ruby-python-php-perl/).